# combine different dataframes into one graph

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I have two dataframes
the first one

```
price = pd.read_csv('top_50_tickers.csv')
     timestamp     GME   MVIS    TSLA    AMC
0   2021-07-23  180.36  13.80  643.38  36.99
1   2021-07-22  178.85  14.18  649.26  37.24
2   2021-07-21  185.81  15.03  655.29  40.78
3   2021-07-20  191.18  14.41  660.50  43.09
4   2021-07-19  173.49  13.67  646.22  34.62
```

the second one

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('discussion_thread_data.csv')
tickers                        dt  AMC  GME  MVIS  TSLA
0       2021-03-19 21:00:00+06:00   11   13     0    11
1       2021-03-19 22:00:00+06:00    0    0     3     0
2       2021-03-19 23:00:00+06:00    0    5     0     3
3       2021-03-20 00:00:00+06:00    4    0     6     0
```

I want to put column AMC,GME.. from the first dataframe on top of AMC, GME from another dataframe.
I want to have 4 separate graph with merged graphs on top of each other
Here is what I have but it works only with one ticker
So I assume I need to loop through each column

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(frame_on=False)
ax.plot(price.timestamp, price.GME, color="C0")
ax.axes.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax2.plot(df1.dt, df1.GME, color="C1")
ax2.yaxis.set_label_position("Ticker Occurence")
ax2.yaxis.tick_right()
ax.set_xlabel('Time Frame')
ax.set_ylabel('Price')
```

Appreciate any help

Comment: Are you saying you have two dataframes with lots of matched columns, and you want to create lots of merged graphs, merging one column at a time? E.g. AMC-AMC from the two dataframes, then GME-GME in a different graph, etc?

Comment: Yes that is what I want

Answer (score 2):

Put all lines in the same subplot, e.g.:

```
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.plot(price.timestamp, price.GME, color="C0")
ax.plot(df1.dt, df1.GME, color="C1")
```

etc.

Comment: can you do it in a for loop otherwise it is redundant

Comment: I have around 50 tickers and wouldn't be able to write them manually

Comment: I don't understand: Your question is about how to combine lines in a single graph, and in the example you use different variable names. If in fact you have a list of dataframes, then loop over the list and plot each dataframe. You can use `label` instead of `color` to distinguish them, and supply some label from the dataframe or from some other iterable. Or something along these lines. I do not see any of this in your question, so I'm not sure which variant would be applicable to you.

Answer (score 0):

I generally find it more easy using [subplots](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) instead of `figure` e.g

```py
#Get plotting-columns
plot_cols = df1.columns[1:] #assuming the first columns is not to be plotted, but the rest are


fig,axes= plt.subplots(len(plot_cols),1) #rows x columns 

#Plot them

for i,col in enumerate(plot_cols):  #i = index, col = column-name
   
   axes[i].plot(price.timestamp,price[col])
   axes[i].plot(df1.dt,df1[col])
    .
    .
   #do other stuff with axes[i]
```

Comment: yeah but how do I combine two datasets into one graph and then graph 4 graphs that overlap

Comment: I think you'll need to provide a visual expected outcome - its rather difficult to understand how you want it to look

Comment: Do you need two plots with the same columns from each dataframe in the same plots e.g `GME` from `df1` and `prices` in plot 1, `AMC` from `df1` and `prices` in plot2 etc or...?

Comment: yeah and in total I want 4 graphs with the same pattern

Comment: Then just do as above - but plot what you want in the same `ax` object

Comment: I was thinking about a for loop that would find column names from one dataset and in another dataset and plot both of them. Otherwise it is redundant because I have around 50 tickers and here 4 tickers is just an example

Comment: yeah GME AMC TSLA are columns

Comment: It doesn't graph and gives this error TypeError: 'Figure' object is not subscriptable

Comment: yeah, my bad - `fig` and `axes` should be switched around (I have updated the answer)

Comment: Now it gives this issue TypeError: tzinfo argument must be None or of a tzinfo subclass, not type 'UnitData'

Comment: That is an issue of your data-structure

Comment: yeah I fixed it thank you. One last thing can you help me putting labels of the specific column on each graph. Thank you

Comment: just add `col` as legend-name in your loop, since `col` contains the column-name being plotted. Can be done in different ways e.g by setting `label=col` as argument to `ax.plot` https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend.html

Comment: when i do like this     ticker = mpatches.Patch(color='white', label=col) plt.legend(handles=[ticker]) it is giving me a legend only for the last one